# Yahoo OAuth 2.0 - could not retrieve Access Token

Tags: php, api, yahoo, yahoo-api

I'm trying to implement Yahoo OAuth 2.0 to import contacts to my application. I'm using PHP, and this guide (Server-side Apps part) :

https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide

I have created my app, authorize access and receive my code

> "authorization code is appended to the redirect_uri, shown below as
>   code=abcdef"

I've successfully arrive at step 4.
https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/#step-4-exchange-authorization-code-for-access-token

Here, I cannot get a response for https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token and receive my Access Token.

I'm using https://github.com/saurabhsahni/php-yahoo-oauth2/blob/master/YahooOAuth2.class.php class.

**Here is my code :**

```
include_once("/libraries/Yahoo/YahooOAuth2.class.php");

// step 1, step2, step3     
// Successfully received authorization code and stored in my session
[...]

//my Client ID (Consumer Key)    
$cc_key = 'x3485sdfsfsdfsdfsdf[..]';

//Client Secret (Consumer Secret)    
$cc_secret = '3423423fddssdfsdf';


//my authorization code receive    
$code = $_GET['code'];

define("CONSUMER_KEY",'$cc_key');
define("CONSUMER_SECRET",$cc_secret);
$redirect_uri="http://dev.example.com/user/register-step4";


$token=$oauth2client->get_access_token(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,$redirect_uri,$code);
```

I'm getting 401 error: 
"Received error: 401 Raw response:{"error":"invalid_grant"}"

From yahoo api errors:

> 401 invalid_grant : An invalid or expired token was provided.

This is not true, because my authorize code should be good, because I just received exactly like in the specifications.

**Related problems:**

https://developer.yahoo.com/forum/Messenger-IM-SDK/not-getting-response-for-https-api-login-yahoo-com-oauth-v2-get-request-token/1310023528000-09714556-4cd3-38c5-b799-d29e8d5f9bcb/

Comment: what did you set the `redirect_uri` value to in the redirect request to the authorization endpoint?

Comment: The redirect_uri should be included in the request, according to the documentation https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/#step-4-exchange-authorization-code-for-access-token. See section "Get Access Token (/get_token) Request Parameters" . The redirect_uri is actually the url that yahoo will redirect and needs to send my new token.

Comment: The redirect_uri value that i used in step 2 , is the same redirect_uri that I try to use in this step: "http://dev.example.com/user/register-step4"; For authorization code worked perfectly, and yahoo redirected to my redirect uri with my authorization code.

Comment: you can try using curl manually to get the token directly and verify if your code is breaking or something else; this works for me: `curl -v -u "<cc_key>:<cc_secret" -d "grant_type=authorization_code&code=<code>&redirect_uri=http://dev.example.com/user/register-step4" https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token`

Comment: I tried the above command in terminal :  i receive a long response, but some of the lines are:    Connected to api.login.yahoo.com (188.125.80.138) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations   [...]  Authorization: Basic ... [...] WWW-Authenticate: invalid_grant  Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Age: 1
< Connection: close
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000
* Server ATS is not blacklisted
< Server: ATS< 
* Closing connection 0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):   No token is included in my response :(

Comment: Yahoo api documentation is awful.